# Error with packagin app for win10 with nw.js

Tags: nw.js

I package my app with nw.js v.0.14.0 and v.0.12.3. For win 10 I have this error: `[0414/135120:ERROR:main_dll_loader_win.cc(134)] Failed to load NW DLL from C:\Users\Roman\Desktop\win64\nw.dll: Не найден указанный модуль. (0x7E)`. When I start my app on Linux or OSX app start.

Comment: You mean for OSX and Linux the application starts? The error occurs for .12.3 and .14.0?

Comment: Yes, for Linux and OSX application starts. This error occurs for .14.0